# Qt5 Сообщение об ошибке

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Как убрать ошибку при сборке приложения в Qt5 : QTM_USE_NAMESPACE does not name a type?

gpstest.h:

```
#ifndef GPSTEST_H
#define GPSTEST_H
#include <QtWebSockets>
#include <QObject>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QOrientationSensor>
#include <QGeoPositionInfoSource>
//#include <qmobilityglobal.h>
//#include <orientation.h>

QTM_USE_NAMESPACE
class gpsTest : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit gpsTest(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:
    void gotCoordinates(QVariant,QVariant);

public slots:
    void slotPositionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo info);
    void slotPositionTimeout();
};

#endif // GPSTEST_H
```

Настраиваю проект:

```
QT += core gui network location positioning xml quick websockets
CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY += location
```

Comment: Приведите код на который ругается компилятор

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё решилось простым перезапуском проекта с чистого листа (с настройками всех компиляторов).

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте `#include <qmobilityglobal.h>`

Comment: Добавляю его в свой "gpstest.h" - ругается на него..нет такого файла или каталога..